# Jetpack Compose Kotlin says

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm passing a lambda to a composable to trigger on Modifier.clickable but the compiler warns that "The expression is unused"

Why would this be happening and how to correct it? Very weird?

[Screenshot of compiler warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLDCB.png)

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(dateVM: DateViewModel = DateViewModel(), dateList: List<DateList>) {

    val dayIndexState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Column {
        ShowDateScroll(dateIndex = dayIndexState.value) {
            newDateIndex -> dayIndexState.value = newDateIndex
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShowDateScroll(
    dateIndex: Int,
    dateIndexUpdate: (newIndexState: Int) -> Unit
) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.LightGray),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(25.dp)
    ) {
        items(items = dateList, itemContent = { dateItem ->
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable(
                        role = Role.Button
                    ) {
                        dateIndexUpdate
                    }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = dateItem.dow
                )
                Text(
                    text = dateItem.day.toString(),
                )
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code you passed in the trailing lambda will never execute.

A trailing lambda itself is a function, if you just write down another function name nothing will happen.
Compare to:

```kotlin
fun function() {}
fun other() {
  function
}
```

If you never use the function / invoke it. Thus it is unused.

In order to invoke the code you have different options:
Replace the trailing lambda with the function reference

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(
  role = Role.Button,
  onClick = dateIndexUpdate,
)
```

Another way is to invoke the function:

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(
  role = Role.Button,
) {
  dateIndexUpdate()
  /* or */
  dateIndexUpdate.invoke()
}
```

In your code the second option can be used with clickable because you need to provide the parameter:

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(
  role = Role.Button,
) {
  dateIndexUpdate(dateIndex)
  /* or */
  dateIndexUpdate.invoke(dateIndex)
}
```

Not sure if it is the correct index, you need to adjust it for your code.

Comment: Thanks - I feel like a real idiot for not spotting that - Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just referencing the method. You must invoke it to use it. Like `dateIndexUpdate(...)`. Add the new index state in the parameter, or whatever your use case is